# Can't I write relative path in React.js？

Tags: javascript

I am making an application transite several pages by seeing [the pages](https://rara-world.com/react-native-router-flux/).

The error happens

```
Failed to compile

./src/Router.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './pages/pageA' in '/Users/xxx/app/frontend/src'
```

I wrote in src/Router.js

```
import React, { Scene, Router, Actions  } from 'react';
import pageA from './pages/pageA';
import pageB from './pages/pageB';
import pageC from './pages/pageC';

const RouterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Scene>
        <Scene
          key="pageA"
          component={pageA}
          title="Page A"
          rightTitle="toB"
          onRight={() => { Actions.pageB(); }}
        />
        <Scene
          key="pageB"
          component={pageB}
          title="Page B"
          rightTitle="toC"
          onRight={() => { Actions.pageC(); }}
        />
        <Scene key="pageC" component={pageC} title="Page C" />
      </Scene>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default RouterComponent;
```

Directory structure is
[image]

Can't I write relative path in React.js？How should I fix this?

Comment: Move the `pages` directory inside `src` directory. That should work.

Comment: @DanO Why did you remove [tag:reactjs]?

Comment: because the question has nothing to do with reactjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `pages` directory is not inside `src` directory or sibling of `Router.js`. **Move the `pages` directory inside `src` directory. That should work.**

Now read on...

You can have write relative URLs and you have to write that way, but unfortunately, your directory structure says, you have the crucial JavaScript files out of the `src` folder. Please put the `pages` folder into the `src` folder and this should work.

Always have all the necessary JavaScript files inside the `src` folder for React to compile and work. None of the files should be out of it.